# Return the enum key instead of the integer value when encoding into JSON

Tags: typescript

My typescript is returning the integer value for an enum when it is converted to a JSON string, how can I return the actual enum key (as a string)?

```
export enum ProductType {
   Retail,
   Digital
}

export interface Product {
   id number;
   productType ProductType;
}
```

In the string representation that is sent to my API server I get:

```
JSON.stringify(product)

"productType": 0
```

But I need it to be `"productType" : "Digital"`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you use an enum your only option is to do that conversion yourself like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mxae1W), since enum values are not the same as the keys.  Are you sure you need an enum? You could just use the string literals if that's what you care about, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wQYpGw).  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz no b/c my other enum types have more properties than just that...

Comment: Sorry, I need more detail. What about either of my suggestions doesn’t work for other enums? Please [edit] the question to show a use case that the suggestions won’t satisfy.

Answer (score 0):

> But I need it to be "productType" : "Digital"

## Issue

Enums are number by default.

```
export enum ProductType {
   Retail,
   Digital
}

console.log(ProductType.Retail); // 0
```

## Fix

You can declare a `string` enum though:

```
export enum ProductType {
   Retail = "Retail",
   Digital = "Digital"
}

console.log(ProductType.Retail); // Retail
```

Comment: I want other enum properties also ... not just a single string field.